# Calling a functor in a std::map with boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, bind, functor

I was having trouble with this, and I couldn't find a solution on SO. It took me a while to figure it out so I thought I'd post it, in case its useful for someone else

Problem:
I have a set of functors of different types, which I want to store in a std::map and then call later sort of like a switch statement/factory.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void operator() (int x) {
        std::cout << "In foo" << x << std::endl;
    }
};
class Bar {
public:
    void operator() (int x) {
        std::cout << "In Bar" << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The map looks like

```
std::map<int,boost::function<void(int)>> maps;
```

And the inserts look like

```
maps.insert(std::make_pair(1,boost::bind(&Foo::operator(),Foo(),_1)));
```

And you can call it like

```
auto iter = maps.find(1);
iter->second(123);
```

Looking at the solution it's quite simple one liner, compared to the mental gymnastics trying to figure it out - oh well :)

What i was trying to do originally was to store boost::signals2::signal objects so I could chain a set of factories,in the map, but I never did figure that out. So for a question, how would I store those instead in a map?

```
std::map<std::string,boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>> m_factory;
// Create the object I want to store
boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> sig;
sig.connect(Foo());
// This fails
m_factory.insert(std::make_pair("Blah",sig));
```

but I get

```
std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&
```

**Edit Simplified the example further**

**Edit 2 - fix bug where I declared map with reference**

Further to this, this seems to work fine

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> Signal;
m_factory["Blah"] = Signal().connect(Foo());
```

which I thought was logically the same as make_pair?

Comment: You know you can post a question and answer it yourself, right? That's probably the best approach for the first chunk of this. As for your signals problem, why have you declared the map value to be a reference?

Comment: Fixed typo. I didn't know about answering your own question - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::signals are non-copyable, which makes them not suitable to be used with std containers. You should use pointers (possibly smart pointers) to the signal as in

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> sig;
typedef std::shared_ptr<sig> pSig;
typedef std::map<int, pSig> map_sig;

void f(int){}

int main(){
    pSig s(new sig);
    s->connect(f);

    map_sig m;
    m.insert( map_sig::value_type(1, s) );
}
```

(you can try the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ba9338b665e064bce17f4ba67243e044-4c14052776b81b965e3761ffd8f9b825)).

Comment: This works, but not if I change it back to operator() and add a return type. Then it fails again. Still will upvote for first part

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=46f24febb99398d9747092e00517111d-4c14052776b81b965e3761ffd8f9b825 I probably misunderstood your comment. Thank you for upvoting. If what you find at the link is not what you meant, let me know